# Delete cell in column if value matches value in array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have VBA delete cells in column Z.  I found a code snippet that I have been playing with (below), however, it is very slow.  There must be a quicker way to perform this task.  I know using `.Select` slows this down, but for now, it works.  Any speed enhancement ideas will be much appreciated.  Also, adding a dynamic row count to set the range would be great, too.

```
Sub DeleteValues()          'This works but is really slow
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Arr(1 To 7) As String

Arr(1) = "First search item"
Arr(2) = "Second search item"
Arr(3) = "Third search item"
Arr(4) = "Fourth search item"
Arr(5) = "Fifth search item"
Arr(6) = "Sixth search item"
Arr(7) = "Seventh search item"

Range("Z1").Select

    With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False

For x = 1 To 70          'for 70 rows
    For i = 1 To 7       'number of items in the Array
        If ActiveCell.Value = Arr(i) Then
            ActiveCell.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next x

            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If this code works and you are just looking to improve it, it may be a better candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) That said you can repeat `Range("Z1:Z70").Replace("First search item","")` 7 times. With only 70 cells, replace should work fast enough

Comment: 1. loop backwards through the range.  2.  After finding a positive match exit the inner loop. 3.  Use `Range("Z" & i).Value` and get rid of all the `.Select` and `ActiveCell` lines.

Comment: If you want it really fast use variant arrays and stop looping the range itself.

Comment: I decided to go with the Autofilter method, much faster.